# Java Code for Inventory Program Part 3 will not compile

Tags: java

Made correction to previous errors, this error now comes up.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\AdminUser\My Documents\InventoryPart3.java:93: invalid method declaration; return type required
public Television(int ItemNumber, String ProductName, int UnitsStock, double UnitPrice, String mfgName) {
       ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1
```

---

```
 class Television { //class name and attributes

    private String ItemNumber; //item # of product
    private String ProductName; //product name
    private double UnitsStock; //# of units in stock
    private double UnitPrice; //Price per unit
    private String SerialNumber; //serial number of product
    private double InventoryValue; //The dollar value of the inventory in stock

//constructor

 public Television (String item, String product, double units, double price, String serial) {

    ItemNumber = item;
    ProductName = product;
    UnitsStock = units;
    UnitPrice = price;
    SerialNumber = serial;

} //end constructor

///getter and setter methods for Television

public void setItemNumber (String item) { //setter for item number
    this.ItemNumber = item;
} //end setter item number

public String getItemNumber() { //getter for item number
    return ItemNumber;
} //end getter item number

public void setProductName (String product) { //setter for product name
    this.ProductName = product;
} //end setter product name

public String getProductName() { //getter for product name
    return ProductName;
} //end getter product name

public void setUnitsStock (double units) { //setter for units in stock
    this.UnitsStock = units;
} //end setter units in stock

public double getUnitsStock() { //getter for units in stock
    return UnitsStock;
} //end getter units in stock

public void setUnitPrice (double price) { //setter for unit price
    this.UnitPrice = price;
} //end setter unit price

public double getUnitPrice() { //getter for unit price
    return UnitPrice;
} //end getter for unit price

public void setSerialNumber (String serial) { //setter for serial number
    this.SerialNumber = serial;
}//end setter for serial number

public String getSerialNumber() { //getter for serial number
    return SerialNumber;
}//end getter for serial number



//calculate individual product inventory value

public double getInventoryValue(){
    return UnitsStock * UnitPrice;

}//end calculate individual product inventory value


//calculate total inventory value
public double calculateInventory(){
    return UnitPrice * UnitsStock;
}//end calculate total inventory value

///end getter and setter methods for Laptop

} //end class Television

class Manufacturer extends Television {
private String manufacturerName;

//constructor

public Television(int ItemNumber, String ProductName, int UnitsStock, double UnitPrice, String mfgName) {
    super(ItemNumber, ProductName, UnitsStock, UnitPrice, ManufacturerName);

    this.manufacturerName = mfgName;

}//end constructor

//getter and setter for class Manufacturer

public void setmanufacturerName(String mfgName) {
    this.manufacturerName = mfgName;
}

public String getmanufacturerName() {
    return manufacturerName;
}

//end getter and setter for class Manufacturer

//calculate total inventory value

public double calculateInventory(){
    return ((UnitPrice * UnitsStock));

}//end calculate total inventory value

//calculate restocking fee method

public double getcalculateRestockFee() {
    return getInventoryValue();

    }//end calculate restocking fee method

}//end class Manufacturer
```

Comment: Please try to write more useful titles. "Do Not Understand Error Messages Java Code for Inverntory Part 3 Confused, frustrated Need Help." provides very little information about what your question is about, and much of it adds no value at all. I've made an edit for you, this time.

Comment: I will make sure not to make that mistake again. So that I follow the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two errors. The first one occurs on line 93 of the file InventoryPart3.java. On that line you will find the code:

```
 super(ItemNumber, ProductName, UnitsStock, UnitPrice);
```

Which is actually a call to the constructor of the television class. However, the constructor of the television class accepts 5 parameters: String, String, double, double, String but you are passing only 4.

The second error occurs on line 120 of the same file. In this case you seem to be calling a method but you left out the parenthesis. That is, the code should be:

```
   getInventoryValue()
```

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\AdminUser\My Documents\InventoryPart3.java:93: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Television(int,java.lang.String,int,double)
location: class Television
  super(ItemNumber, ProductName, UnitsStock, UnitPrice);
  ^
1 error

Tool completed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of television which you are trying to call from the manufacturer class using super does not exist in television class. Please see the parameters in the super() call and the actual parameters in the Television constructor. The getInventoryValue function is not there in the Television class.Hence it is throwing an error for the super.getInventory call

Answer (score 0):

The first error is related to your Television constructor.  Your Television constructor takes 5 arguments of type String, String, double, double, String.  In your Manufacturer class, you're calling the superclass constructor with an int, string, int, and double.  In a subclass, your super() constructor call must match one of the constructors in the base class (Television).

For the second error, your call to getInventoryValue has a syntax error.  To call a method in Java, you have to put parentheses after the name of the method:

```
return super.getInventoryValue() * 0.10;
```

Note that in this case, the `super.` part is optional.  The getInventoryMethod() exists in the super class, and is not private, so you can call it from the subclass like this:

```
return getInventoryValue() * 0.10;
```